# Position animation with jquery in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I found dozens of similar questions here, but none of the ones I read gave a definite answer to my question: How do I animate positions using jQuery in IE8 ?

The same code that works on all other browsers, doesn't work in IE8.

Here's my case:
I have a footer which contains a navigation divided into 2 pieces - each 100% screen width wide. To show the second part of the menu, I use animations.

Here's my footer code:

```
<div id="footer-wrapper">   

            <footer id="footer">                        
                <div id="menu-wrapper-primary">             
                    <nav class="menu-main-menu-container">
                        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
                            <li id="menu-item-37" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-37">
                            ... 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>              
                    <div id="menu-next">
                        <span class="menu-next-text">more this way</span>
                        <img src="design/img/menu_more.png" alt="menu_next">                        
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /menu-wrapper-primary -->

                <div id="menu-wrapper-secondary">   

                    <nav class="menu-secondary-menu-container">
                        <ul id="menu-secondary-menu" class="menu">                      
                            <li id="menu-item-483" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-483">
                            ...
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </nav>  

                    <div id="menu-prev">
                        <img src="/design/img/menu_back.png" alt="menu_previous">
                        <span class="menu-back-text">back to main menu</span>   
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /menu-wrapper-secondary -->

            </footer>

    </div>
```

Here's the relevant css:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    width: 200%;
    background: black;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    position: relative;
    height: 45px !important;
    top: 1px;
}

#menu-wrapper-primary, #menu-wrapper-secondary {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
}
```

And this is the JS:

```
$( '#menu-next' ).click( function(){
        $( '#footer' ).animate( { left: '-49%' }, 'slow' )
    } );    
    $( '#menu-prev' ).click( function(){
        $( '#footer' ).animate( { left: '0' }, 'slow' )
    } );
```